# Function to load textures not working correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

So I wrote a helper function that just loads a png file disc and loads it into an OpenGL shader.

This all works fine and well until I try to load multiple textures. The problem that I run into is the fact it seems to overrite all previous textures each time. I have no idea why this is happening. If the code I am providing isn't enough, the full source is posted [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32ztnjr6ltjmi0k/AABOB9P3CdWRR84q9L1o1wRga?dl=0)

Here is the loadTexture function (resides in Helper.cpp)

```
GLuint loadTexture(const GLchar* filepath, GLuint& width, GLuint& height)
{
    // image vector.
    vector<GLubyte> img;

    // decodes the image to img
    decode(img, filepath, width, height);

    // if the image is empty return
    if (img.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Bad Image" << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    // return value
    GLuint ret;

    // gen textures
    glGenTextures(1, &ret);

    // bind the ret to GL_TEXTURE_2D so everyting using GL_TEXTURE_2D referrs to ret
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ret);

    // set parameters. Current filtering techunique is GL_LINEAR http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tut15%20Magnification.html
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // copy the data to the texture associated with ret. 
    // format is RGBA internally and externally, and the size is unsigned char, which is unsigned byte
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &img[0]);

    return ret;

}
```

The decode method saves the image to img and stores the width and height to width and height respectively.

If there is something that I am missing please tell me.

Thanks for any help I can get!

Comment: Why not use a dynamic memory allocation for this case?

Comment: Never done it before. How would I go about that?

Comment: First you allocate memory for your gluint variable then when you are done with the memory you delete it.

Comment: Delete the cpu or GPU memory? I still need the gpu memory because this is only called during initialization, so I haven't actually drawn it yet. Also, am I Wong to think that the cpu memory is being deleted when the function returns because img is a local variable?

Comment: I agree with Irrational Person, as the rest of the code looks good. It's just using the 'vecor' that seems a bit suspect, and you should be deleting the local image data before returning as it's not always deleted automatically just 'cos it's declared locally. Different versions of different compilers do that differently. Best to allocate and free within the function.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson: This is about the dumbest advice I've read in a long while. Dynamic allocation is not going to help you at all here. Why? Because it's just an integer. When dynamically allocating you still need that space on the stack, now for the pointer, instead for the int, which is at least as large. And then on the heap you get a single integer allocated + it's management overhead. *Don't dynamically allocate small temporary fixed sized stuff. It's bad. Just don't do it.* **If you're dynamically allocating and freeing single `int`s you're doing it wrong!**

Comment: @GavinSimpson: The problem is somewhere else. See my answer. People don't look at the texture loading functions. In OpenGL it's all about the drawing code.

Comment: @RussellGreene: Your texture load function is fine. std::vector is C++ idiomatic and does RAII. GLuint for the texture is a single integer, living on the stack and since every call of the function gets a new stack frame and the GLuint is just a handle, there's no need (or sense) to allocate it dynamically. Disregard anything regarding dynamic allocation here, because these people are clueless. std::vector does dynamic allocation internally, but since it's RAII deallocation happens behind the scenes without having to worry about it.

Comment: Ok, ok!. lol. I like your style Mr datenwolf, and consider myself dunced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something doesn't work with OpenGL, always look in the drawing code first. In your draw function (I hate Dropbox, BTW, first have to download that shit so that I can view it) there's this:

```
        GLuint uniID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex");

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glUniform1i(textures[idx], 0);
```

That's your problem right there. `textures[idx]` contains the textureIDs. But the texture ID does not go into a shader uniform at all. The first parameter to glUniform… is the so called "location index" of the shader variable. Right above the uniform location of a shader variable called `tex` is queried. *That* is what goes into the uniform call. The value is the number of the *active texture* unit.

To select the actual texture to be used, you have to *bind* the right texture to the right texture unit. Your original code lacked to bind the desired texture when it was needed.

Use this code:

```
glUseProgram(program)
GLuint uniID = glGetUniformLocation(program, "tex");
for(…) {
    /* ... */
    int const unit = 0; // just for illustration
    glUniform1i(uniID, unit);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + unit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[idx]);
    /* draw stuff ...*/
}
```

BTW: Textures are not loaded into shaders.

Comment: Thanks, will check when I power on my computer. Makes enough sense though :)

Comment: Hey, what provider should I use to provide my entire source code when I don't want to copy paste it in?

Comment: @RussellGreene: Well, on StackOverflow the idiomatic, recommended way is to actually copy and paste the source code. If you really want to link to it use GitHub; makes things for people answering a lot easier, too, since a GitHub repo is quickly cloned so that you can compile and test at your local machine.